# Equation to approximate a Partition-like function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, approximation, integer-partitions

The partition function for $n$, $P(n)$ gives the number of partitions that exist for $n$.

I've been trying to find a function that gives the number of partitions where order matters, e.g. $1+2+3$ is considered a different entry from $2+3+1$. If a sum consists of only one element such as $2+2+2$, it is only counted once.

Does such a function exist (has any extensive research been conducted into it)?

What about an approximation for such a function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called the [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of a number $n$. There are $2^{n-1}$ of them, as the Wikipedia article notes, simply because there are $n-1$ spaces in the expression $$ (1 \square 1 \square 1 \dotsb \square 1) $$
containing $n$ "$1$"s, into which one can insert either a "$,$" or a "$+$", to give any list which sums to $n$, and these are all distinct.